# Expression.Call nested functions

Tags: c#, lambda, func

I have a nested func like so: `Func<A, Func<B, C>>`.

I'm trying to construct an expression tree that is able to:

- Call the outer func
- Call the returned func

The issue I seem to be running into is that `Expression.Call` requires the target and method info ahead of time, and that's not known (or I don't know how to get it) until the func comes back from the first call.

There must be a way of doing this, but so far I'm stuck after the first call.

Comment: having an interface to wrap the expected function into is no option?

Comment: @Vulpex I mean, I could, but I'd like to avoid it if possible, this *must* be possible though, surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to solve this myself, it ended up being a gap in my knowledge.

The answer is that because `Func<_>` is a delegate, you can use `Expression.Invoke` instead of `Expression.Call`, and `Expression.Invoke` supports operating over an expression value as opposed to requiring target and method information up-front.